# plotly partial_bundle fails with timeout error

Tags: r, r-plotly

I'm trying to increase the performance of a markdown which has a lot of plotly graphs in it by using the partial_bundle function. I'm using the code from the ?partial_bundle for the reprex

Unfortunately it fails with the error message:
Error in curl::curl_download(paste0("https://cdn.plot.ly/", bundle_script),  :
Timeout was reached: [] Connection timed out after 10012 milliseconds

```
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% 
  add_heatmap() %>%
  partial_bundle()
```

Now I am behind a VPN at work, so I assume that is causing an error, but unsure how to redirect the package if needed. Also is there a way to download the required "bundle" directly from the cdn or npm package directly, as listed here https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md
?

Many thanks. I appreciate that as this isn't reproducible (you'd need to be behind my VPN), just wondered if anyone else had come across this issue and resolved it!

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue... Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't I'm afraid!